# ASP .NET Entity Framework Database not initialized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, localdb

I have created an ASP .NET MVC application with simple login and sign up functionality, and am trying to create an Entity Framework 6 model using Code First Approach. I am using LocalDb to create the database. However, I get the following exception when I add

```
<contexts>
  <context type="WebApplication1.DAL.ProjectContext, WebApplication1">
    <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication1.DAL.ProjectInitializer, WebApplication1"/>
  </context>
</contexts>
```

to the Web.config file. The exception is below:

Most of stack trace is:

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'WebApplication1.DAL.ProjectContext' from assembly 'WebApplication1'.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +106
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +62
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError) +46
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +47

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to set database initializer of type 'WebApplication1.DAL.ProjectInitializer, WebApplication1' for DbContext type 'WebApplication1.DAL.ProjectContext, WebApplication1' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +327
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass6.<TryGetInitializerFromEntityFrameworkSection>b__1(ContextElement e) +276
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +223
```

Here is the ProjectContext.cs code:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models.DAL{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.Models.DAL;

public partial class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext(): base()
    {

    }
    public DbSet<PIP> PIP { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Project { get; set; }

}
}
```

Here is the ProjectInitializer.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Models.DAL
{
    public class ProjectInitializer:System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProjectContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProjectContext context)
        {
            var projects = new List<Project>
            {
                new Project{ ProjectID=1, Name="New ADM", StartDate=new DateTime(2017,1,10), EndDate=new DateTime(2017,2,10),},
                new Project{ ProjectID=2, Name="New ADM", StartDate=new DateTime(2016,5,20), EndDate=new DateTime(2016,6,20),},
                new Project{ ProjectID=3, Name="New ADM", StartDate=new DateTime(2015,8,30), EndDate=new DateTime(2015,9,30),}
            };

            projects.ForEach(pr => context.Project.Add(pr));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var PIP = new List<PIP>
            {
                new PIP{ PIPID=1, ProjectID=1 },
                new PIP{ PIPID=2, ProjectID=2 },
                new PIP{ PIPID=3, ProjectID=3 },
            };
            PIP.ForEach(pip => context.PIP.Add(pip));
            context.SaveChanges();

            Database.SetInitializer<ProjectContext>(new ProjectInitializer());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share `ProjectContext` and `ProjectInitializer` code

Comment: I've editied the question to include them

Comment: You are using wrong namespace in config, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

When creating code first entity framework application, there is no need to add context:

> In the Code-First approach, you focus on the domain of your
>   application and start creating classes for your domain entity rather
>   than design your database first and then create the classes which
>   match your database design

Meaning, you do not need context (designer) to access your db, you create your own classes to communicate with your db.

please read more about code first at [entityframework tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx) site.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will definitely go through that link!  I was actually following this tutorial, and they added context to set up the database initializer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#set-up-ef-to-initialize-the-database-with-test-data

Comment: You this at the end by migration, all is explained in the link I attached :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong namespace for `ProjectContext` and `ProjectInitializer` classes in `web.config`, it should be `WebApplication1.Models.DAL` instead of `WebApplication1.DAL`.

```
<contexts>
  <context type="WebApplication1.Models.DAL.ProjectContext, WebApplication1">
    <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication1.Models.DAL.ProjectInitializer, WebApplication1"/>
  </context>
</contexts>
```